# Sorting array in 5 minute interval with unique value count

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to sort an array in such a way that i get the count for unique users during an interval of 5 minutes starting at 0:00 at the start of the day.
how do i define the 5 minute interval in epoch time? (the used data will be the epochtime of the current day) and how do i get the unique usercount for that interval?

**Input**

```
[1486428994000, "user a"]    

[1486429834000, "user a"]

[1486429839000, "user a"]

[1486429869000, "user b"]
```

**Desired output**

```
[1486428900000, 1 ]

[1486429800000, 2 ]
```

Comment: 5 minutes in (millisecond) epoch time is `5 * 60 * 1000`…

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Remove doublons from an array.
const uniq = array =>
  array.filter((value, index) => array.indexOf(value) === index);

// Your function.
const groupCount = (data, timeWindow) =>
  data
    .reduce((groups, line) => {
      const current = groups[groups.length - 1];
      // If the line is outside of the current time window, push a new group.
      if (!current || line[0] > current[0] + timeWindow) {
        // Find the beginning of the corresponding time window.
        const windowStart = line[0] - line[0] % timeWindow;
        // Push the new group.
        groups.push([windowStart, [line[1]]]);
      } else {
        // Else add a new user to the group.
        current[1].push(line[1]);
      }
      return groups;
    }, [])
    // Once we created the groups, we remove doublons from them and count users.
    .map(group => [group[0], uniq(group[1]).length]);

const data = [
  [1486428994000, "user a"],
  [1486429834000, "user a"],
  [1486429839000, "user a"],
  [1486429869000, "user b"]
];
console.log(groupCount(data, 5 * 60 * 1000));
```

Answer (score 0):

To set a repeating timer, you can use `setInterval(function(){},_timeout_)`

```
var T = setInterval(function(){
 /* code here */
}, 1e3*60*5);
```

1e3 = 1000 (milliseconds)
x 60 (seconds)
x 5 (minutes)

for "now" in Javascript you can use:

`new Date().valueOf()`

depending on which type of epoch you're using you might have to divide or multiply by 100

To get unique values, you can use `.reduce()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Gotchas using client side timers:

your JS time stamp takes the machine time, so if the client's machine date/time is off, your calculations will be wrong - the best way to combat this is to send a server time stamp to the front end and cast that into a javascript date object and work with that, rather than the client's machine time.

As mentioned, the epoch time stamp varies from server software to server software, so you might have to adjust either server side or client side (usually a difference of a factor of a 100)

Answer (score 0):

With some timestamp logic and some array magic, you can pull this off.  Although the below solution returns the correct output, I feel like the map at the end isn't entirely necessary.  If anyone feels like expanding on my solution, please feel free to.

```js
var raw = [
  [1486428994000, "user a"],
  [1486429834000, "user a"],
  [1486429839000, "user a"],
  [1486429869000, "user b"]
];
raw.map(a=> a[0] = parseInt(a[0] / (5 * 60 * 1000)) * (5 * 60 * 1000));
raw = raw.reduce(function(a,b) {
  if(!a[b[0]]) a[b[0]] = {users: [], count: 0};
  if(a[b[0]].users.indexOf(b[1]) === -1) { a[b[0]].users.push(b[1]); a[b[0]].count++; }
  return a;
}, {});
var ret = [];
for(var i in raw) {
  ret.push([i, raw[i].count]);
}
console.log(ret);
```